# How to consistently use grid layout with components in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid-layout

I am developing a web app and I want to use CSS grid layout. After few hours, I figured out most of my layouts were incorrect because the `style` was overwritten by lower component, losing `gridArea`. I had just been lucky it had worked so far.

Because I believe it's the container's responsibility to place items, items should be agnostic of whatever `gridArea` the upper component decides to assign them. Moreover, I have factories of components so I sometimes just don't know which item will be there. I am now doing this boilerplate in all my components:

```
<div style={{ ...props.style, ...styles.ThisComponent }}>
  my item content...
</div>
```

What is the correct way of doing it? Any pitfall?

I am rewriting all my components now, please save me a lot of efforts!

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid is only supported by the most recent browsers.
Wouldn't you prefer using Grid layout from material-ui? Then you can adjust everything. Here's a [link](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/) if you do, there's also a CSS Grid layout exanplation there.

Comment: Thanks, I already looked into material-ui and I will certainly need to use it at some point. At the moment, I just want to make the `display: grid` work consistently :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coding the styles property in all the components you will ever write like above seems to be an overkill. Also, using a fallback for browsers without CSS-Grid support should also be a priority.

Have you tried creating wrappers in `styled-components` and then putting your component code inside ? Could potentially save you the trouble if all the outer `div`s should have the same style ? The syntax may change a bit from what you have written, but seems more maintainable*

*might be opinionated

Comment: I have not tried that, I am not sure what it would look like. Could you show me an example?